# What are health benefits of eating vegetable salad with some portion of chicken daily?

Tags: diet

I want to know health benefits of eating vegetable salad with grilled chicken and sauce as vinegar.

In vegetables cabbage is in excessive quantity with onions, cucumber, boiled corn and olives.

Will this meal daily can impact weight loss for me. I'm 5'6" with 85kg.

Comment: It depends on what you are eating on the other meals. If you create a caloric deficit ( consuming less calories than you burn ) you will loose weight.

Comment: Need to rephrase this question to relate to physical fitness. I'm betting that is why you picked this site to post right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no healthy or unhealthy food, only healthy and unhealthy diets, meaning it's what you eat in total during the days and the whole period that counts. If you eat little enough to lose weight, it will typically be beneficial for your health if you are overweight.

However, some foods will make you more full, meaning it's easier to eat less for the rest of the day. Vegetables and salad contain few calories but have high fibre content and large volume, meaning you'll feel full. Chicken is high in protein which is good if you want to maintain muscle while losing fat. So in that regard, it's a good meal, yes. If you have a pizza and coke in the evening, your diet is still bad.

Comment: Thanks for making me feel guilty whenever I'm eating pizza! :-P

Comment: Sorry! :P A real serving of pizza where I'm from is about 1200-1600kcal, you just can't compensate for that with salad.

Comment: For one slice? Holy cow! What's in it?

Comment: No, by a _real_ serving I meant what one typically actually eats when one has pizza where I'm from, which is a whole one, thin crust.